# What is the possible value of $x$ in the following case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$2^{y}+2(3^{y}) > 3(4^{y})$$ and $$y=3x^2+2x-2$$

Which of the following is a possible value of $x$?

$A -1.5 $

$B-2.5 $

$C -0.5 $

$D+0.7 $

$E+1.2$

$********$

I could just conclude from the $1st$ inequality that $$y∊(-∞, 0)$$
Should I put values of $y$ e.g. $-1, -2$ and then check or is there some other way?

I couldn't approach further. Please help.

Comment: $2^y-4^y>2(4^y-3^y)$ =>  RHS>0 and LHS <0, for y>0. Clearly, y=0 is not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of the quadratic are $\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{28}}{6}$. So $y$ is negative only for $\frac{-2-\sqrt{28}}{6}\lt x \lt \frac{-2+\sqrt{28}}{6}$. The smaller root is about $-1.2$, and the larger is about $0.5$.

Combine this with your observation that $y \le 0$, and note that only one of the given values of $x$ lies in the right range.

Comment: Option $C$ sir if I get you right.

Comment: @TheApe: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's no clever thought required.  You've got five possible values for $x$.  Each of these five values gives you a unique value for $y$.  Try each of these five values in the original inequality, and see which values make it true and which make it false.  If you have a decent calculator, you should be able to check each of the five possibilities in about 30 seconds apiece; so you'll have the answer in under 3 minutes.